# Error starting application in .netcore

Tags: iis, localhost, asp.net-core, startup

I'm getting the following error when navigating to my IIS published .netcore application:

[image]

I have set up my web.config file as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\KritnerWebsite.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Not sure if this warning is relevant or just outdated:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
>   Warning     The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'aspNetCore'. List of possible elements expected: 'asp, caching, cgi, defaultDocument, directoryBrowse, globalModules, handlers, httpCompression, webSocket, httpErrors, httpLogging, httpProtocol, httpRedirect, httpTracing, isapiFilters, modules, applicationInitialization, odbcLogging, security, serverRuntime, serverSideInclude, staticContent, tracing, urlCompression, validation, management, rewrite'.    KritnerWebsite  D:\gitWorkspace\KritnerWebsite\src\KritnerWebsite\web.config    12  Build

The line in the web.config was as per the template, I just changed "false" to "true" for `stdoutLogEnabled`.

I have also created an empty folder in the root directory "logs" - I wasn't sure if this should get created automatically or not.  Either way, nothing is being written to the logs, so I am not sure what to try next.

I have opened the solution in VS2015 on my host, compiled it and ran it successfully through commandline/localhost with `dotnet run`.  This is running it in the production configuration, so pulling from my environment variables for insights key, and connection string.  So I'm not sure why the site would run successfully on my host through `dotnet run` but not when published to IIS

How do I get further information on what the error is?

Comment: You installed the required tools (which includes ASP.NET Core Module for IIS) on your server? And .NET Core Runtime if you are creating a portable app?

Comment: @Tseng indeed, it was running successfully last night at some point.  Additionally a log file did write in a previous publish... it's just not now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly caused the logs to start correctly recording in `./logs`... but they did.  With the exception now being recorded I could see that my connection string I had set up in my Environment Variables was off.

Still not sure what caused the logs to not write out in order for me to determine this faster.

After updating my environment variable and running `iisreset` as per https://serverfault.com/questions/193609/make-iis-see-updated-environment-path-variable my website is now being served properly.

Comment: Did the The element 'system.webServer' has invalid child element 'aspNetCore' warning disappeared?